# VSCode Include Folder but exclude its subdirectory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to search within a directory (say `./cpp`), but then exclude one of the subfolders, say `./cpp/build`. How do I go about it? This is on Windows 11 if that matters. Thanks.

[image].

Comment: Works fine for me. What happens when you try it?

Comment: Check in the files.exclude settings of your settings.json file. What do you have there? Probably some configuration is excluding the subfolder. Also, verify that the subfolder has the necessary permissions in the folder settings.

Comment: @JoseJC I think a solution that requires editing settings for each different search is a rather poor workaround.

Comment: I second wjandrea's comment. works fine for me. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.